# Given a handle to a subplot, can I find the associated subplot index in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, subplot

I have multiple subplots in a figure. I also have the handle to one of the subplots, which I got through use of the `ginputax` function described [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/297774).

I now want to get the (integer) subplot index from the handle, so I can plot to the subplot using the [subplot](http://www.mathworks.co.jp/help/techdoc/ref/subplot.html) command.

```
[~, ~, ~, subplot_handle] = ginputax(1);
subplot_idx = ?function?( subplot_handle)     %# this is the bit I don't know how to do
subplot(u, v, subplot_idx);
plot(x, y);
```

Is there an easy way to get this index? I realise I could alternatively plot directly to the subplot handle, but I would prefer to get the index out.

Comment: Ahh.. good point, didn't realise subplot had this functionality. Post as an answer and I'll accept. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a handle to the subplot, you can use `subplot(subplot_handle)` to plot in an existing subplot.

Answer (score 2):

From what I know not directly as subplots are just axes.

But indirect are many ways:

1. you could store the information in the `Tag` or `Userdata` of the subplot eg. `b=subplot(2,2,3,'Tag','pos3')` - use `get(b,'Tag')` (my favourite)
2. you could just store the handles in order and then search.
3. you could figure out using `Position` from the handle.